# [Brownie]: Aave Flashloan - Calling lending.pool.borrow() does not actually borrow

Tags: brownie, flash-loans

My code run successfully without errors, but it never does actually borrow anything from Aave when i call lending_pool.borrow(). Tried running this on both a mainnet-fork into local environment, as well as on kovan testnet.

Screenshot of output below is from Kovan testnet.

Borrow transaction hash on Kovan testnet: 0x44278d3d74c607a5417f6c7d1c81b43cecb872ee22a635280ad3bf0edabb29fc

[image]

My code:

```
from scripts.helpful_scripts import get_account
from brownie import network, config, interface
from scripts.get_weth import get_weth
from web3 import Web3

#0.1 ETH - 0.1*(10**18)
deposit_amount = Web3.toWei(0.1, "ether")  

def get_lendingpool():
    # create lending_pool_addressess_provider contract object
    lending_pool_addressess_provider = interface.ILendingPoolAddressesProvider(config["networks"][network.show_active()]["lending_pool_addressess_provider"])
    #get lending pool address
    lending_pool = lending_pool_addressess_provider.getLendingPool()
    return lending_pool

def approve_erc20(amount,spender, erc20_address, account):
    print("....Approving ERC20 token...")
    # get ERC20 interface: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/aave_brownie_py_freecode/tree/main/interfaces
    # approve(address spender, uint256 value)
    erc20 = interface.IERC20(erc20_address)
    tx = erc20.approve(spender,amount,{"from": account})
    tx.wait(1)
    print("....Approved....")
    return tx

def get_borrowable_data(lending_pool,account):
    (totalCollateralETH, totalDebtETH, availableBorrowsETH, currentLiquidationThreshold, ltv, healthFactor) = lending_pool.getUserAccountData(account)
    
    # all ETH values are denominated in WEI - convert to ETH
    total_collateral_eth = Web3.fromWei(totalCollateralETH, "ether")
    total_debt_eth = Web3.fromWei(totalDebtETH, "ether")
    available_borrow_ETH = Web3.fromWei(availableBorrowsETH, "ether")

    print(f"...You have {total_collateral_eth} worth of ETH deposited...")
    print(f"...You have {total_debt_eth} worth of ETH borrowed...")
    print(f"...You can borrow {available_borrow_ETH} worth of ETH...")
    return (float(available_borrow_ETH), float(total_debt_eth))

def get_token_price(token_price_feed_address):
    # use chainlink pricefeed
    token_eth_price_feed = interface.AggregatorV3Interface(token_price_feed_address)
    price = token_eth_price_feed.latestRoundData()[1]   #price is index 1 
    norm_price = Web3.fromWei(price, "ether")
    print(f"...DAI/ETH price is {norm_price}")
    return float(price)


def main():
    account = get_account()
    deposit_token_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["weth_token"]
    # if no WETH, get_weth()
    # local mainnet fork can use dummy acocunts to get WETH
    # since local mainnet fork, can use dummy accounts. if actual mainnet/testnet then use private key account.
    if network.show_active() in ["mainnet-fork"]:
        get_weth()

    # Get lending pool contract
    lending_pool_address = get_lendingpool()
    lending_pool = interface.ILendingPool(lending_pool_address)
    print(f"....Lending pool contract: {lending_pool_address}....")

    ## Approve before sending our ERC20(WETH) tokens: approve allowance of deposit_amount for Aave lendingPool contract
    approve_erc20(deposit_amount, lending_pool.address, deposit_token_address, account)

    # Deposit: deposit(address asset, uint256 amount, address onBehalfOf, uint16 referralCode)
    ## referralCode is deprecated - just pass a 0 as parameter
    print("....Depositing....")
    tx = lending_pool.deposit(deposit_token_address, deposit_amount, account.address, 0, {"from": account})
    tx.wait(1) # wait one block
    print("....Deposited!....")

    # Borrow DAI
    ## how much can we borrow - pull account stats - getUserAccountData(address user)
    (borrowable_eth, total_debt_eth) = get_borrowable_data(lending_pool,account)
    
    ## DAI in terms of ETH
    dai_eth_price = get_token_price(config["networks"][network.show_active()]["dai_eth_price_feed"])
    
    ## how much DAI can we borrow?
    dai_to_borrow = (1/ dai_eth_price) * (borrowable_eth *0.95)#use 90% of collateral: liquidation concerns
    print(f"...We will borrow {dai_to_borrow} DAI...")
    dai_in_wei = Web3.toWei(dai_to_borrow, "ether") 
    print(f"...We will borrow {dai_in_wei} DAI...")
    
    ## Borrow! call borrow() from lendingPool contract
    ## function borrow(address asset, uint256 amount, uint256 interestRateMode, uint16 referralCode, address onBehalfOf)
    # interestRateMode: 1 - stable | 2 - variable
    dai_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()]["dai_token_address"]
    borrow = lending_pool.borrow(dai_address, dai_in_wei, 1, 0, account.address, {"from": account})
    borrow.wait(1)
    print("...Borrowed!...")

    # Account Info
    get_borrowable_data(lending_pool,account)

    # Return DAI
    ## repay(address asset, uint256 amount, uint256 rateMode, address onBehalfOf)
    repay_all(dai_in_wei, lending_pool, account)
    get_borrowable_data(lending_pool, account)



def repay_all(amount, lending_pool, account):
    approve_erc20(Web3.toWei(amount, "ether"), lending_pool.address, config["networks"][network.show_active()]["dai_token_address"], account)
    repay_tx = lending_pool.repay(
        config["networks"][network.show_active()]["dai_token_address"], 
        amount, 1, account.address, {"from": account})
    repay_tx.wait(1)
    print("...REPAID....")
```

Comment: your provided tx hash interacting DAI token smart contract. can you provide your borrow tx hash?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the fixed code? Working with the same repo :)

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue, get_token_price was returning token price before converting to Wei - hence i was trying to borrow some figurein the range of E-16.